# What are some examples of MemberBinding LINQ expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

There are three possibilities, but I can't find examples:

1. System.Linq.Expressions.MemberAssignment
2. System.Linq.Expressions.MemberListBinding
3. System.Linq.Expressions.MemberMemberBinding

I want to write some unit tests to see if I can handle them, but I don't know how to write them except for the first one, which seems to be `new Foo { Property = "value" }` where **Property = "value"** is an expression of type `MemberAssignment`.

See also this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberbinding.aspx).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The classes I'm using in these examples are as follows:

```
public class Node
{
  //initialise non-null, so we can use the MemberMemberBinding
  private NodeData _data = new NodeData();
  public NodeData Data { get { return _data; } set { _data = value; } }
  //initialise with one element so you can see how a MemberListBind
  //actually adds elements to those in a list, not creating it new.
  //Note - can't set the element to 'new Node()' as we get a Stack Overflow!
  private IList<Node> _children = new List<Node>() { null };
  public IList<Node> Children 
    { get { return _children; } set { _children = value; } }
}

public class NodeData
{
  private static int _counter = 0;
  //allows us to count the number of instances being created.
  public readonly int ID = ++_counter;
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Firstly, you can get the C# compiler to generate expressions for you to investigate how they work more by doing the following:

```
Expression<Func<Node>> = () => new Node();
```

Will generate an inline expression that contains a call to `Expression.New`, passing the ConstructorInfo of the Node type.  Open the output DLL in Reflector to see what I mean.

I should first mention that these three expression types you ask about are typically passed in a MemberBinding[] array in an Expression.New, or embedded within each other (since Member initializers are inherently recursive).

On to the plot...

### MemberAssignment

The MemberAssignment expression represents the ***setting*** of a single member of a new instance with the return value of a given expression.  It is produced in code using the `Expression.Bind` factory method.  This is the most common that you'll see, and in C# code this is equivalent to the following:

```
new NodeData() { /* start */ Name = "hello" /* end */ };
```

or

```
new Node() { /* start */ Data = new NodeData() /* end */ };
```

### MemberMemberBinding

The MemberMemberBinding represents the inline initialisation of the members of a member that is already initialised (i.e. newed, or a struct that can't be null anyway).  It is created through the `Expression.MemberBind` and ***does not represent creating a new instance***.  Therefore, it differs from the MemberBind method by not taking a ConstructorInfo, but a reference to a Property Get method (property accessor).  As a result, an attempt to initialise a member in this way that starts off null will result in a NullReferenceException.

So, to generate this in code you do this:

```
new Node() { /* start */ Data = { Name = "hello world" } /* end */};
```

This might seem a bit odd, but what's happening here is that the property get method for `Data` is being executed to obtain a reference to the already initialised member.  With that in hand, the inner MemberBindings are then executed in turn, so effectively the above code is not overwriting Data, but doing this:

```
new Node().Data.Name = "hello world";
```

And this is why this expression type is required, because if you've got to set multiple property values, you can't do it in a one-liner,  unless there's some special expression/syntax to do it.  If `NodeData` had another string member (`OtherName`) that you also wanted to set at the same time, without initialiser syntax/expressions, you'd have to do this:

```
var node = new Node();
node.Data.Name = "first";
node.Data.OtherName = "second";
```

Which isn't a one liner - but this is:

```
var node = new Node() { Data = { Name = "first", OtherName="second" } };
```

Where the `Data =` bit is the MemberMemberBinding.

I hope that's clear!

### MemberListBinding

Created by the `Expression.ListBind` method (requiring also calls to `Expression.ElementInit`), this is similar to the MemberMemberBinding (in that an object's member is ***not*** being created anew), but this time, it's an instance of ICollection/IList that is being ***added to*** with inline elements.:

```
new Node() { /* start */ Children = { new Node(), new Node() } /* end */ };
```

So, these last two expressions are kinda edge-cases, but certainly are things that you could well come across, as they are clearly very useful.

Finally, I enclose a unit test that you can run that will prove the assertions I make about these expressions - and if you reflect the method body, you'll see that the relevant factory methods are being called at the points I highlight with the comment blocks:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
  Expression<Func<Node>> e = 
    () => new Node() { Data = new NodeData() };

  Expression<Func<Node>> e2 = 
    () => new Node() { Data = { Name = "MemberMemberBinding" } };

  Expression<Func<Node>> e3 = 
    () => new Node() { Children = { new Node(), new Node() } };

  var f = e.Compile();
  var f2 = e2.Compile();
  var f3 = e3.Compile();

  var node = f();
  //proves that this data was created anew as part of the expression.
  Assert.AreEqual(2, node.Data.ID);
  var node2 = f2();
  //proves that the data node's name was merely initialised, and that the
  //node data itself was not created anew within the expression.
  Assert.AreEqual(3, node2.Data.ID);
  Assert.AreEqual("MemberMemberBinding", node2.Data.Name);
  var node3 = f3();
  //count is three because the two elements in the MemberListBinding
  //merely added two to the existing first null item.
  Assert.AreEqual(3, node3.Children.Count);
}
```

There you go, I think that should cover it.

Whether you should be supporting them in your code is another matter! ;)

Comment: Wow... I did not even know that the last two were legal in C#!

Comment: @luksan - I too learned a lot in researching the answer! I can say that I haven't taken advantage of these features of c#/.net expressions as yet, but one day...